# ncat echo server, write incoming message to shell?

Tags: linux, server, netcat, nmap

Is there a way to get ncat to print what it receives to the terminal before it echos back on the port with cat, Looks like the executed code doesn't have access to stdio?

I think tee is supposed copy stdout to cat with something like this, but I don't see any output.

```
ncat -e '/usr/bin/tee > (/bin/cat)' -l -p 2048
```